# Which ISPs has the cheapest transfer?

Tags: domain-transfer, isp, cheap

There are a lot websites where you upload file and many people download it. I guess these servers are located in ISP where the transfer is very cheap, I guess Europe, because US has expensive transfer data.

I mean sites like 4shared, yousendit, filestube, fileserve, ... and other "movie repository" sites :P

Where are they usually hosted to get cheaper transfer data ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First off, sites like 4shared/fileserve/mediafire are file hosting/file sharing sites. They're not "movie repository" sites. Most people use them for legal storage and sending files too large to be attached to an email. And filestube is just a search engine for file sharing sites. They don't host anything.

Secondly, large websites of any kind generally use content distribution networks. They're not hosted in a single country. And every country has cheap and expensive web hosts, including the U.S. It doesn't make sense to get a Nigerian web host just to save $10/month in bandwidth costs if it means your site will be slow to all of your users.

Comment: Lese's answer is very to the point.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for concrete / actual recommendations - you can get a cheap VPS with lots of bandwidth these days (in the US and elsewhere).   For starters - you can get a VPS with  1 / 1.5 TB monthly bandwidth for $5 a month. See if you find something to suit your need on http://www.lowendbox.com.